# jivo site клавиатура перекрывает текстовое поле webview

Tags: android

Клавиатура перекрывает текстовое поле.
Как сделать так чтобы текстовое поле не перекрывалось, а просто сдвигалось вверх?

Я поставил в манифесте

```
<activity
            android:name=".sc_navs.SupportServiceActivity"
            android:label="@string/support_service"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="jivoapi" />
```

установлено в style

```
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
```

Но все равно клавиатура закрывает окно.

JivoActivity унаследованно от фрагмента.

Answer (score -1):

замените

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

на

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`